# windows 10 powershell list all installed features, updates, programs, and hotfixes applied to a system; in order of date applied

Tags: powershell, windows-10

In Windows 10, using power-shell how do I list all installed features, updates, programs, and hotfixes applied to a system; in order of date applied.

I see that Get-HotFix will do all Updates and Security Updates, but not .NET framework features or programs.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you post the code you are encountering the issue with? StackOverflow is designed to assist with specific issues encountered while writing code. If you need something written for you I recommend you higher a programmer to do so for you as StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: google around a bit. `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | ? State -eq Enabled`

Answer (score 1):

Using the query below this will have the Installed date first and then name version and vendor.

```
$installedProducts = Get-WmiObject Win32_Product | select installdate, name,version, vendor | Sort-Object installdate -Descending
```

The install date is described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378(v=vs.85).aspx

And the format of the data is described here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387237(v=vs.85).aspx